# How do you prove $e^x=\exp x$ for real, non-rational $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Let $\exp x=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac {x^n}{n!}$. Let $e=\exp 1$.

Let $a,x\in \Bbb R$, $a>0$. We define $a^x=\sup \{a^r:r\in \Bbb Q, r<x\}$.

I've already proved that for $x=\frac pq \in \Bbb Q$, $a^x=\sqrt[q]{a^p}$ (where I've already proved the existence of roots, and $a^p=\prod_{i=1}^p a$), and using this, that $\exp (1)^r=\exp (r)$ for rational $r$.

Now want to show that $e^x$, i.e $\exp (1)^x=\exp (x)$, but the $\sup$ definition seems too hard to use.

Could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: As far as I can see, you only have to prove that $\exp$ is increasing and continuous. The continuity directly follows from the representation via a power series.

Comment: The definition given for $a^{x}$ works only when $a\geq1$. For $0<a<1$ you need the infimum of $a^{r}$ or you need to reverse inequality to $r>x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a = \exp(1) > 1$ we can prove the equality using your definition of $a^x$ as follows.

Let $(r_n)$ be an increasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $x$. You need to show that $a^{r_n} \to a^x$.

Once you have proved this then by continuity of $\exp(\cdot)$ we have

$$\exp(1)^x = \lim_{n \to \infty}\exp(1)^{r_n} =  \lim_{n \to \infty}\exp(r_n) =  \exp(\lim_{n \to \infty}r_n) = \exp(x).$$

With $a = \exp(1) > 1$ we see that $a^{r_n}$ is bounded  above by $a^x$since

$$a^{r_n} \leqslant \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a^{r_n} \leqslant \sup \{a^r:r\in \Bbb Q, r<x\} = a^x.$$

For rationals, $a^r$ is increasing. If $r > s$, then $a^r = a^{r-s}a^s$. Since $r - s > 0$ it is straightforward to show for  $a > 1$ that $a^{r - s} > 1$ and, therefore $a^{r} > a^{s}.$ Hence, $(a^{r_n})$ is an increasing sequence.

We claim that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a^{r_n} = a^x.$ Assume to the contrary that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a^{r_n} < a^x.$ Then there exists a rational number $r < x$ such that $a^{r_n} < a^{r}$ for all $n$.  However, since $r_n \to x$ there exists $m$ such that $r_m >r$.  This implies $a^r < a^{r_m}$, a contradiction.

Therefore,

$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a^{r_n} = a^x.$$

By monotone convergence

$$a^{r_n} \to a^x.$$